Acento en base de datos mysql utf-8
tengo el siguiente problema. tengo un codigo de un carrito de compras, todo funciona bien ecepto que cuando oprimo realizar compra, el correo me llega perfecto sin problemas de escritura ni nada. con su formato utf-8 bien... pero cuando se registra en la base de datos se registran con errores los nombres que tienen acento.... ya he revisado el codigo de arriba para abajo pero no soy tan experto en este tema y no se donde puede estar la falla. Anexo el codigo donde inserta los datos en la base de datos para ver si el problema esta ahi y alguien me puede ayudar a detectarlo.
codigo del archivo que inserta los datos en la base de datos
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require '../vendor/autoload.php'; // Asegúrate de incluir el autoload de PHPMailer

// Obtener los datos del cuerpo de la solicitud
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$datos = json_decode($inputJSON, true);

require_once "../config/conexion.php";
require_once "../config/config.php";

// Crear el contenido del correo electrónico en formato HTML
$mensaje = "
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Pedido de productos</title>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }
            th, td {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Detalle del pedido</h2>
        <p><strong>Nombre:</strong> " . $datos['nombre'] . "</p>
        <p><strong>Correo electrónico:</strong> " . $datos['correo'] . "</p>
        <p><strong>Teléfono:</strong> " . $datos['telefono'] . "</p>
        <p><strong>Opción de entrega:</strong> " . $datos['tipoentrega'] . "</p>
        <p><strong>Dirección de entrega:</strong> " . $datos['direccionentrega'] . "</p>        
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>";
$total = 0;
$jsonProductos = [];
foreach ($datos['productos'] as $producto) {
    $id = $producto['id'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = $id");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $jsonProductos[] = [
        'id' => $id,
        'codigo' => $result['codigo'],
        'nombre' => $result['nombre'],
        'precio' => $result['precio_rebajado'],
        'cantidad' => $producto['cantidad']
    ];

    

    $total += $result['precio_rebajado'] * $producto['cantidad'];

    $mensaje .= "
            <tr>
                <td>" . $id . "</td>
                <td>" . $result['codigo'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $result['nombre'] . "</td>
                <td>" . number_format($result['precio_rebajado'], 2) . "</td>
                <td>" . $producto['cantidad'] . "</td>
                <td>" . number_format(($result['precio_rebajado'] * $producto['cantidad']), 2) . "</td>
            </tr>";
}

$mensaje .= "
            <tr>
                <td colspan='5'><strong>Total</strong></td>
                <td><strong>" . number_format($total, 2) . "</strong></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>";

// Configurar PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = HOST_SMTP; // Configura el servidor SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = USER_SMTP; // Configura el correo electrónico para autenticación SMTP
$mail->Password = CLAVE_SMTP; // Configura la contraseña del correo electrónico para autenticación SMTP
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
$mail->Port = PUERTO_SMTP;

$mail->setFrom($datos['correo'], $datos['nombre']);
$mail->addAddress(CORREO); // Agrega el destinatario

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Pedido de productos';
$mail->Body = $mensaje;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';


// Enviar el correo electrónico
if ($mail->send()) {
   

 //REGISTRAR PEDIDO
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $datos['nombre']);
    $correo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $datos['correo']);
    $telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $datos['telefono']);
    $tipoentrega = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $datos['tipoentrega']);
    $direccionentrega = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $datos['direccionentrega']);
    $productos = json_encode($jsonProductos);
    
    // Construir la consulta SQL escapando los valores
    
    
    $query = "INSERT INTO pedidos (fecha, nombre, correo, telefono, total, productos,tipoentrega,direccionentrega) VALUES ('$fecha', '$nombre', '$correo', '$telefono', '$total', '$productos', '$tipoentrega', '$direccionentrega')";

    // Ejecutar la consulta SQL
    if (mysqli_query($conexion, $query)) {
        $respuesta = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Correo enviado correctamente');
    } else {
        $respuesta = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error al registrar el pedido en la base de datos');
    }
} else {
    $respuesta = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error al enviar el correo: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
}

// Devolver respuesta al cliente (JavaScript)
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($respuesta);


Codigo de la conexion a la base de datos
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "";
    $clave = "";
    $bd = "";
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$clave,$bd);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos";
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_select_db($conexion,$bd) or die("No se encuentra la base de datos");
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");

y en resumen el problema es que la palabra marrón por ejemplo se me registra en la base de datos como:

This question is similar to: ¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
